# Remove Vuex store after Electron app is uninstalled

Tags: vue.js, electron, vuex

I have an Electron app on windows and I use the store to determine whether or not a user has completed the program configuration. This is so if they did complete it, the setup page is not displayed when the program is re-opened.

The issue is, when I uninstall the program using the bundled uninstaller and then reinstall it, the program skips the setup page.

I have deleted `vuex.json` in `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\<app name>` but that doesn't help. This is `index.js`, I would like to keep the persistedState

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

import { createPersistedState, createSharedMutations } from 'vuex-electron'

import modules from './modules'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
  modules,
  plugins: [
    
    createPersistedState(),
    createSharedMutations()
  ],
  strict: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
})
```

How can I clear the store on uninstall?

Comment: Did you also delete the Electron folder in AppData?

Comment: @Terry in the roaming folder?  `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Electron`. No I did not, I'll try it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments:

There's a an `Electron` folder in:
`C:\Users\<USERNAME>\AppData\Roaming\Electron`.

You could delete that whole folder or just `vuex.json` or even change the values inside `vuex.json`. This only applies to development builds.

If you've already installed the Electron application (i.e. you build the app for a target platform and ran the installer) the directory on Windows would be `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\<YOUR_APP_NAME>`

Don't know where MacOS puts installed things